# Making my post easier to read

Tags: discussion, support, editing

I tried to make [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448614/defining-a-measure-of-uniformity-for-measurable-subsets-of-0-12-w-r-t-a-sub) easier to read but find it extremely difficult to get through grammatical-wise.

I'm wondering if there is someone who can correct the grammar of this post or rewrite the sentences without changing the meaning.

Comment: ChatGPT? (/sarcasm)

Comment: from what I see, the issue with this post is not the grammar, but the length; you could try to get to the point more quickly; perhaps you could just leave out the "attempt" part?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I made edits, and added the attempt as an answer. Is this better?